# Css : img border and text decoration

Tags: css, image, hyperlink, border

I am trying to fix IE image border problem while having text-decoration on link hover.
the border issue is fixed but the decoration is gone.

```
<a href="home.php" class="menu-links">
<div class="menu-home">Home</div>
<img class="menu-home-logo" src="images/home.png" width="32" height="32">
</a>
```

css :

```
.menu-links {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.menu-links:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.menu-links img {border: none; }
```

Comment: Do you want the image to be underlined?  I used the code above and "Home" is underlined when you hover of the link.

Comment: @Jason No I want the text be underlined when the mouse hovers the link. and I want to remove the border because in IE there is a border around img.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you included is working properly in Internet Explorer and Firefox.  Home is underlined when you hover and the image has no border.  If you want the image to be underlined as well as the text, you'll need to add `border-bottom` rather than `text-decoration` to the image on hover:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .menu-links { color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
            .menu-links:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
            .menu-links img { border: none; }
            .menu-links:hover img { border-bottom: 1px solid #000; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="home.php" class="menu-links">
            <div class="menu-home">Home</div>
            <img class="menu-home-logo" src="images/home.png" width="32" height="32">
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

If that's not showing up right, you've probably got some other CSS interfering with the styles you posted above.  Use a debugger like Firebug to analyze the control and see what's preventing the underline from showing up.

Comment: Yeah it's not showing... I really don't understand what is going on. It does work on DreamWeaver but not when I upload the file and check it through browser. It shouldn't be cache issue since I can see the changed sources. got confused

Comment: Do you have any way to share the entire page?

Comment: I can't share the page itself but here is the entire css file : http://pastebin.com/nGerzidF I think you are right something has conflict with the underline. Tried your code with my css file and it doesn't work. seems something is wrong with my css

Comment: It looks like you're absolutely positioning your menu-home-logo.  Is it possible it's too close to the text and is sitting on top of the underline?  Try changing to `top:19px;` or something just to eliminate that as a possibility

Comment: No it seems changing its top doesn't affect the underlined text at all. Tried giving it -50px or 100px. no luck

Comment: Ok found the problem... had to change `.menu-links` to `.menu-links div` and `.menu-links:hover` to `.menu-links div:hover`